# Repetition in regular expression shows no result anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, regular-expression, windows

I have a Windows-10 machine, on which I've installed a Ubuntu platform, as can be seen in following `uname -a` result:

```
Linux DOMINIQUEDS 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have some files which contain lots of entries like:

```
18bd6344        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[1046]
18bd63f4        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[1046]
18bd64a4        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[1046]
18bdcef4        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[4]
18bdcfa4        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[8]
18bdd054        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[49]
18bdd104        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[498]
18bdd1b4        mfc110u!CPtrArray        Size:[498]
```

The mentioned sizes vary from 1 to many millions, and I'm interested in the larger ones, let's say the ones who contain at least three digits.

I can do this using following regular expression:

```
grep "Size:\[[0-9][0-9][0-9]" Log1.log // this is working fine
```

I expected following regular expression to give the same result:

```
grep "Size:\[[0-9]{3,}" Log1.log
```

But I get nothing.

I've just verified `man grep`, and this explanation contains the following:

> ...
>      Repetition
>          ...
>          {n,}   The preceding item is matched n or more times.

So why is this not working?

Comment: `grep "Size:\[[0-9]\{3,\}" Log1.log`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: please put this as an answer, I'll confirm it immediately. It works as a charm :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's on Ubuntu, I'm guessing you have GNU grep. The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) also says:

> grep understands three different versions of regular expression syntax: “basic” (BRE), “extended” (ERE) and “perl” (PCRE).
>          In  GNU grep,  there  is  no  difference  in  available  functionality  between  basic  and  extended  syntaxes.  In other
>          implementations, basic regular expressions are less powerful.  **The  following  description  applies  to  extended  regular
>          expressions**;  differences  for  basic  regular expressions are summarized afterwards.

And then:

> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**
>          In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`,  and  `)`  lose  their  special  meaning;  instead  use  the
>          backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

So, you need to either use `\{3,\}`, or use the `-E` flag to enable EREs. I'd suggest the latter, since those backslashes everywhere get ugly rather quickly.

Comment: `grep -E "Size:\[[0-9]{3,}"` is workin fine indeed, and it looks better than the solution with the backslashes. :-)